# DAX Excel LOOKUPVALUE between two tables

Tags: excel, dax, xlookup

I have a question regarding DAX in Excel.

I have two tables:

Table 1 = General journal entries

Table 2 = Trialbalance

I would like to create this Excel function in DAX:

=IF(XLOOKUP(B2,CW_TB!A:A,CW_TB!E:E)=0,"1","")

=IF(XLOOKUP(Table1[Value],Table2[ValueColumn],Table2[ValueReturn])=0,"1","")

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you researched the `LOOKUPVALUE` function?

Comment: Yes, but i can't get it to work.

=CALCULATE(COUNTAX(tblDataUserCW;IF(LOOKUPVALUE(tblDataCW[FY0];tblDataCW[Konto];tblDataUserCW[Konto])=0;"1";"0")))

Comment: I got it to work with:
=CALCULATE(COUNTA(tblDataUserCW[Bilag]);Filter(tblDataUserCW;IF(LOOKUPVALUE(tblDataCW[FY0];tblDataCW[Konto];tblDataUserCW[Konto])=0;"1";"0")))